# What version of JavaScript does Titanium use?

Tags: javascript, titanium

I'm trying to find out what features of JavaScript I can use in Titanium Appcelerator. I've noticed that it has both forEach and map on Arrays, so I guess it's JavaScript language version is least 1.6 (in [MDCs's terms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/New_in_JavaScript_1.6)). But does it reach further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm on an Appcelerator Titanium webinar this morning and I asked your question.

Here is their answer:

- Not sure of the exact version (e.g., 1.7 or 1.8)
- Using Rhino Javascript interpreter on Android
- Using Webkit Javascript interpreter on the iPhone

So you can basically figure the answer out (exact Javascript version) based on these answers, but the person leading the call (Kevin Whinnery) didn't know the answer off the top of his head.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I guess one could deduce the JS support from the phones' browsers then, so the exact numbers shouldn't be that important.