# Can we use javascript typed array in Titanium Studio

Tags: javascript, titanium, ecmascript-5

I'd like to know if it is possible to get [typed arrays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/br212485(v=vs.94).aspx) to work with Titanium?

I looked over [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369429/what-version-of-javascript-does-titanium-use) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) to get some intel.
[Wiki Ecma script](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=strawman:typed_arrays) then [Ecma International](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm)

But Titanium seem to use version 5, not 5.1, does knows something about it?

Comment: If you try a typed array and it doesn’t work, there’s no way around it, assuming you’re using typed arrays for optimization as is typical.

Comment: You can use `Buffer` instead of typed arrays... http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.Buffer

Comment: Actually, I was trying to use typed array to simulate a byte array to be able to send file to an existing SOAP Web service via javascript. So, Titanium.Buffer seem to be quite close of what I'm looking for.
I'll check it out, thanks